# Shared memory: MapViewOfFile returns error 5

Tags: c++, winapi, shared-memory

I need a mechanism to share memory between some threads (usually in the same process, but sometimes not).

This code, which seems very basic, fails with error 5 (access denied) on `MapViewOfFile`:

```
HANDLE hSharedMemCreated = CreateFileMapping(
    INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,    // use paging file
    NULL,                    // default security
    PAGE_READWRITE,          // read/write access
    0,                       // maximum object size (high-order DWORD)
    10000,                // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)
    "testFileMapping");                 // name of mapping object
HANDLE hSharedMemOpened = OpenFileMapping(
    PAGE_READWRITE,          // read/write access
    FALSE,
    "testFileMapping"
);
void* location = MapViewOfFile(
    hSharedMemOpened,   // handle to map object
    FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, // read/write permission
    0,
    0,
    10);
```

- `MapViewOfFile` succeeds with the opened handle `hSharedMemOpened` with permission `FILE_MAP_READ`.
- `MapViewOfFile` succeeds with the created handle `hSharedMemCreated` with permission `FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS`.
- `MapViewOfFile` fails with the opened handle `hSharedMemOpened` with permission `FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS`.

Comment: In `MapViewOfFile()`, `FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS` is equivalent to `FILE_MAP_WRITE`. Are you SURE you are opening a mapping object that was created with write permissions? Are you calling `CreateFileMapping()` and `OpenFileMapping()` in separate processes? If not, you shouldn't be using them together at all, let alone giving the mapping object a name.

Comment: `PAGE_READWRITE` is not a valid argument for `OpenFileMapping()`. You probably want `FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the comments:

`PAGE_READWRITE` is not a valid argument for `OpenFileMapping()`. You probably want `FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS` instead.